# PowerPoint Flash properties missing from template

Tags: powerpoint, shockwave

I have some PowerPoint templates that behaves strange in regards to `Shockwave Flash Objects`.

When inserting a `Shockwave Flash Object` in either the template master or in a slide in a document created from this template, I only get a blank properties tool window when I open properties for the object.

If I just start `PowerPoint` and insert the template in the default created slide, all the properties are present as they should be.

What could cause this, and how (if possible) can I fix the template?

The template I use contains password protected macros. While I don't see why this should matter, I suspect it does.
But if the mere presence of password protected macros is causing this, you'd think the problem would go away when the presentation is saved and the macros are lost. Yet the problem persists in the presentation, even after the macros are gone.

I use the following procedure for inserting the object:

1. Activate the `Developer` tab.
2. In the Developer tab, in the `Control` group, choose `More Controls`.
3. From the list of controls, choose `Shockwave Flash Object` and click `OK`.
4. `Draw the object` into the slide or layout-master.
5. `Right click` the object and choose `Properties`.

This will show the properties tool window. In this case completely blank.

How it should look (top) vs. how it looks (bottom):

[image: How it should look][image]

**Note:** Flash Player must be installed (via Internet Explorer it seems) in order for the `Shockwave Flash Object` to show up on the list.
Installing Shockwave Player will add a `Shockwave ActiveX Control` to the list, but this is *not* the type of object in question.

Comment: try here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291875

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to achieve - only the properties tool windows is blank (as shown in the second screenshot) so I cannot use the movie-property as described in your link. That's the problem exactly.